# Stop Synchronous loading of image in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, rss

I have an rss feed made through [this third party library](https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/SwiftFeedParser). I am having a problem while scrolling through the tableview. Whenever I scroll down the label text changes but image changes after a while. During that short span of few seconds I can see the previous image of that row. I want a default image to be seen if it is loading in backend.

Code used for getting this lazy loading in their demo is :

```
func loadImageSynchronouslyFromURLString(_ urlString: String) -> UIImage? {
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.timeoutInterval = 30.0
        var response: URLResponse?
        let error: NSErrorPointer? = nil
        var data: Data?
        do {
            data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, returning: &response)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error??.pointee = error1
            data = nil
        }
        if (data != nil) {
            return UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Below is the code from where this function is getting called :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedItemCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let item = entries![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]   
 if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView {
            if item.mainImage != nil {
                imageView.image = item.mainImage
            } else {
                if item.imageURLsFromDescription == nil || item.imageURLsFromDescription?.count == 0  {
                    item.mainImage = UIImage(named: "roundedDefaultFeed")
                    imageView.image = item.mainImage
                }
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    for imageURLString in item.imageURLsFromDescription! {
                        if let image = self.loadImageSynchronouslyFromURLString(imageURLString) {
                            item.mainImage = image
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                                imageView.image = image
                                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                            })
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    return cell
}
```

Please tell me how to show blank space while loading pic after scrolling.

Comment: Use `asyn` to load the data. Show default image in your `imageView` until your data is received from server.

Comment: Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) third party class.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy can you give an example?

Comment: @Ronak I don't want to use any other third party class. I can't figure out what to change in existing code to stop this.

Answer (score 3):

`UITableViewCell`s are reused to improve performance by avoiding cell instantiation. This is why you see the "last" image until the download finished and your "new" image is set.

`UITableViewCell` has a method called `prepareForReuse()`which is called before reusing the cell.

To fix your issue:

Subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `prepareForReuse()` and (re-)set the image with your place-holder image.

or:

Set your placeholder image in `cellForRowAt:indexPath`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedItemCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let item = entries![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]   
    if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView {

        imageView = myPlaceholderImage // set the placeholder you want to see while downloading the image

        if item.mainImage != nil {
           ...
           // your original code
        }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: My answer should fix the error "Whenever I scroll down the label text changes but image changes after a while. During that short span of few seconds I can see the previous image of that row...."). The error description did not change afaics. `reloadRows` should not be called btw.

Comment: How can i use this prepareForReuse method in my view controller?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Is there some other way through which I avoid calling of loadImageSynchronouslyFromURLString() completely?

Comment: You could download it asynchronous instead of download synchronized and wrap the synchronized call in `DispatchQueue.global.async` but that is kind of the same. You do have to download the image and that does take time. Period.  For nicer code, I would extract all the image stuff to an independent function `downloadImage(for cell:UITableViewCell).